# Cron Job - writing in two files

Tags: php, cron, dreamhost

I have the following cron job in DreamHost which runs Test1.php and writes to Test2.php:

```
 /usr/bin/php /home/Test15/Web/Test1.php>              
 /home/Test15/Web/Test2.php 2>&1
```

How can I make this write to a second file?

Answer (score 0):

Have your Test1.php use `fopen` or `file_put_contents` to write to a second file.

Comment: This is possible too, but this way you would not capture every output of the cron job. For example if the script breaks and outputs only errors.

Comment: @YasenZhelev true but why is the OP writing potential errors to a PHP file?

Comment: :) I do not know. But if the developer wants to see what is actually the output of the script and put it in a file, then 'fopen' is not the best option. This is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use the command `tee`. Type in the shell `man tee` for more information. In you case, if we assume the second file is here /home/Test15/Web/Test3.php, you can use that:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/Test15/Web/Test1.php | tee /home/Test15/Web/Test2.php /home/Test15/Web/Test3.php
```

That should redirect the output to both files.